# How to include multiple condition on get_where in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter

Im trying to include to conditions on my get_where but its not working. Single condition works but I need two conditions. Any idea?

Here's my code:

```
$query = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE, array("$column = " => $id, " $column2 = " => $id2, ));
```

Comment: use `where_in`. The query you wrote will produce `select * from table name where column=id and column2 =id2` it will work only for those records where column has id and column2 has id2. Clear out what you exactly want.Better provide with example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead, I just did this:

```
$query = "select * from ".$this::DB_TABLE." name where $column=? and $column2 = ?";

$sql = $this->db->query($query, array($id,$id2));
```

Thanks, Shaiful Islam :)

Answer (score 3):

As i see you are trying to combine the Active Record with Query, so the best way to declare conditions is:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where('table.column', $condition1);
$this->db->where('table.column2', $condition2);
$this->db->where('table.column3', $condition3);
$q = $this->db->get();

foreach($q->result() as $row){
var_dump($row);
}
```

or

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where(array('table.column' => $condition1, 'table.column2' => $condition2, 'table.column3' => $condition3));
$q = $this->db->get();

foreach($q->result() as $row){
var_dump($row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$where_array = array(
               $column =>$id,
               $column2=>$id2
              );  
$query = $this->db->get_where($this::DB_TABLE,$where_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found one thing with where condition. May be helpful for you.

$this->db->group_start();
$this->db->group_end();

Comment: Hey, please [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) properly. It is not a big issue but best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('table1,table2', array('table1.$id' => $id,'table2.condition' => $condition));
return $query->result_array();
```